# How to count the frequency of lagged variable?

Tags: r, data.table

There is a sample dataset as follow:

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 |

My target is to count the frequency of the event within the lagged period.

That is,

for example

I want to take the count of frequency of lag 3 (That is day1 to day4, or lag 2 to lag 5, lag 3 to lag 6 etc),
first I will count for Day 4 first:

| Day | count | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 1 | NA |
| 3 | 1 | NA |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |

....

The reason why Day 4 will have frequencies of 2 is that,

I count 3 consecutive events as 1:

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

Thus day 1 to day 3 will be counted as 1 event;

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

day 2 to day 4 will be count as another events.

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

The frequency of day 5 is 1 because I count it as this way:

day 3 to day 5 will be count as 0 event.

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 |

day 2 to day 4 will be count as 1 event.

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

Therefore, the frequency of day 5 with lag 3 will be:

| Day | count | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 1 |

The expected dataset is:

| Day | count | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 1 | NA |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 |

---

One more example:

I want to take the count of frequency of lag 4,
first I will count for Day 5 first:

| Day | count | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 1 | NA |
| 3 | 1 | NA |
| 4 | 1 | NA |

....

The reason why Day 5 will have frequencies of 2 is that,

I count 3 consecutive events as 1:

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

Thus day 1 to day 3 will be counted as 1 event;

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

day 2 to day 4 will be count as another event.

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

day 3 to day 5 will be count as zero.

| Day | count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 |

The expected dataset is:

| Day | count | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 1 | NA |
| 3 | 1 | NA |
| 4 | 1 | NA |
| 5 | 0 | 2 |

**Toy Data**

```
data <- data.frame(Day = 1:8, 
                   count = c(rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4)))
```

How to implement it in r? Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

So, your (first) example is a bit misleading since you use the same lagging window and number of consecutive events to look at; but here's a way to do this.

1. Apply a rolling mean with width `k1` (in your scenarios, it seems to be always 3)
2. Use `rollsumr` to get the count of `roll == 1` (i.e. all count are 1) among the `k2` (that you call lag) last observations.
3. It seems you want the values before the k2th row to be NA, so I added a `partial` argument to get that.

```r
freq <- function(x, k1 = 3, k2, partial = TRUE){
  roll = zoo::rollmeanr(x, k = k1, fill = NA)
  cumroll = zoo::rollsumr(roll %in% 1, k = k2 - 1, fill = NA)
  if(partial) {cumroll[1:k2] <- NA}
  cumroll
}
```

Output

```r
library(dplyr)

#First example:
df |> 
  mutate(frequency = freq(count, k1 = 3, k2 = 3, partial = FALSE))

#   Day count frequency
# 1   1     1        NA
# 2   2     1         0
# 3   3     1         1
# 4   4     1         2
# 5   5     0         1
# 6   6     0         0
# 7   7     0         0
# 8   8     0         0

#Second example:
df |> 
  mutate(frequency = freq(count, k1 = 3, k2 = 4))

#   Day count frequency
# 1   1     1        NA
# 2   2     1        NA
# 3   3     1        NA
# 4   4     1        NA
# 5   5     0         2
# 6   6     0         1
# 7   7     0         0
# 8   8     0         0
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: the frequency after the lag period should also be rolled

Comment: What's the lagged period for you?

Comment: That is k = 3,4,5,.., until 21. So I will have 21 columns

Comment: I don't get it, please edit your question to reflect this. Add an expected output so it'll be easier to help you